# Rewrite rule partly rewrite url

Tags: php, .htaccess

http://example.com/test/index.php?cl=view&book=15&page=1 is URL that i have,

and what i need is: http://example.com/test/view?book=15&page=1

In my .htaccess file i write:

```
RewriteRule ^view?book=([0-9]+)&page=([0-9]+) index.php?cl=view&book=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

but for some reason, it doesn't work out

Comment: You probably want something along the lines of `RewriteRule ^view$ index.php?cl=view [QSA]`.

Comment: @deceze yeah, i tried it as well, but the problem is, that in $_GET array i have only **[cl] => view**, and no book and page elements

Comment: @deceze or.. sorry, it was a solution. Thank you